# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {content, author})

Tags: reactjs

This is the part of the code that throws the error :

```
session.subscribe("acme/channel", function(uri, payload){

        console.log("Received message", payload.author);

        var myObject = {
         'content': payload.message,
         'author': { 'username' : payload.author },
       }

        var newMessages = this.state.messages;
        newMessages.push(myObject);
        this.setState({messages: newMessages});

      }.bind(this));
```

I don't know why but it doesn't like it when I use `'author': { 'username' : payload.author }`, but it work with a hard coded string like this one : `'author': { 'username' : "Mit" }`.

The problem isn't coming from "payload.author" because this also works:

```
var myObject = {
         'content': payload.author,
         'author': { 'username' : "Mit" },
       }
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: What does the render() function look like? That error is usually raised while rendering, not from setting the state itself.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by adding an empty string:

```
var myObject = {
         'content': payload.msg,
         'author': { 'username' : payload.author + ""},
       }
```

I don't know why it does that, if someone has a better explanation I can mark his answer.